# "MSMQ Dequeuing can only run against the local machine" Error when I set Error on remote server

Tags: nservicebus, msmq

I am using MSMQ as transport with NServiceBus 6 Beta, when I set the error queue locally, it is fine using:

```
NserviceBusEndpointConfig.SendFailedMessagesTo("Error")
```

As soon as I set error queue on remote server I get the following error

> "MSMQ Dequeuing can only run against the local machine"

I also get this when I set the error queue in the configuration

```
<MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error@adminMachine"/>
```

Do I miss something?

Comment: Cross post of https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/particularsoftware/H9Aek4wZ080

Answer (score 0):

If this is V6 **Beta** there is an issue raised here: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/3787